# How to monitor edittext is empty or single character?

Tags: java, android

I want to trigger button event whenever edittext getting text.

Logic is,
if the edittext contains atleast one character(it should be entered by keyboard or pasted) then button will gone.

if edittext is empty, button will visible.

i cant find right logic within `TextWatcher`

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                  if(s.toString().compareTo("") == 0)
                    button.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
                else
                    button.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
 }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        });
```